# Why don’t we say that magnetic flux changing with position induces an emf?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

As per Faraday’s law of electromagnetic induction, an emf is induced with the rate of change of magnetic flux. But according to one of Faraday’s experiments, relative motion between two coils, or between a coil and magnet induces emf, and hence, electric current. Considering the case of relative motion between a coil and a magnet, flux increases when the magnet is brought in close vicinity of the coil, hence, it is changing with time. But, isn’t the flux also changing with the relative position? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if I move a magnet closer to the coil, the flux increases this is correct. If I move the relative position, this position is a function of time.  why do you think you are going wrong?

Comment: Another way to increase flux is if your magnetic is an electromagnet  you could increase the current to increase flux without changing position

Comment: @jensenpaull But when we say, for the induction of emf, the magnetic flux must be changed w.r.t what? We say time, and not position, don’t we?

Comment: One can easily verify, that the relative position does not change the induction - but a change in magnetic flux does (e.g. by changing the magnetic flux in the coil - compared to relative movement in a homogeneous magnetic field). So if a change in position means a change in magnetic flux, it's still only the flux change which causes the change in the induced emf.

Comment: Well said planet maker, It is the rate of change of flux that matters. Yes the flux changes if you put it closer, but the rate at which that happens is important. hence using Time

Comment: Ohk got it! Thanks everyone.